# Ordenar nós de tree view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, classificação

Em minha tree view tenho vários nós filhos. Todos os nós são criado com números, pois esses identificam um arquivo diferente e são compostos pela data.

Como que eu poderia ordenar esses nós de forma numérica? Ou seja, tipo:

```
Raiz
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

E assim por diante...

Alguém sabe me dizer se isso é possível?

Comment: Coloca um exemplo do seu código, assim tá muito vago. Mostrando a estrutura dá pra tentar encontrar alguma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sim, é possível.**

Você deve criar o seu próprio `Comparer` para e defini-lo como valor da propriedade `TreeViewNodeSorter` da `TreeView`

```
public class NodeSorter : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        TreeNode treeNode1 = (TreeNode)x;
        TreeNode treeNode2 = (TreeNode)y;    

        string.Compare(treeNode1.Text, treeNode2.Text);
    }
}

minhaTreeView.TreeViewNodeSorter = new NodeSorter();
```

E quando precisar reordenar os nós

```
minhaTreeView.Sort();
```